# How can I deform an image?

Tags: java, image

Hello I'm just a beginner in Java.

I have an image like this:

[image]

How can I deform this image to a new form using `java.awt.Graphics2D` like this?

[image: deformed image]

Answer (score 1):

`Java2D` can only do affine transforms. This means that with the same rectangle of your example you can do a parallelogram, not a trapezoid (or the other figure).

I never worked with that, but maybe you find what you need with [Java 3D API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html).

Comment: I just have transformed the first image